# Can I use xdg-mime in nitrous?

Tags: nitrousio

I started to use `nitrous` for a new project and I love it.

However, I need to call `xdg-mime` to automatically open html files in a browser. Apparently, `xdg-mime` is not installed by default on nitrous machines.

Is it possible to install it?